# faster replacement of JQuery.load()?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp, web-applications

I have a JSP index page which contains navigation header and notifications panel and in a specific div in the index.jsp I load the other JSP pages using JQuery.load()

I followed this way to avoid redundancy of the navigation and notification in all pages.

1. Is this approach a best practice?
2. It seems that JQuery.load() is slow, is there any faster way to load pages into the content div in the index,jsp page (except the Iframes)?

Comment: jQuery.load specific latence isn't perceptible. You probably have a problem in your JSP or in another script.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been sold to retrieving big chunks of markup asynchronously - I'd better fetch the whole page, or get an XML/JSON representation of data, to be further styled with [client side templating](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more).

Fetching partials from server asks for implementing hash navigation [which is not trivial, and requires a proper routing framework to maintain links reusable], so think if you are dealing with a *website* or with a *webapp*.

There is one approach I don't like much actually, but it may suit your need: have a peek at [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) - live example is totally clear.